# how to check if id exist in json

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

each time i use .register it will keep just making the account and not checking the id exist and if it does it will say the account is already made.

i've tryed if ctx.author.id not in jsonfile 
and geting it from the file with other code too 
just too much too add

````
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def register(ctx):
    with open('Configs/amounts.json') as f:
        usersidlel = json.loads(f.read())
    if ctx.message.author.id not in usersidlel:
        with open('Configs/amounts.json') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            data[str(ctx.author.id)] = {}
            data[str(ctx.author.id)]['cash'] = 100
            data[str(ctx.author.id)]['bank'] = 100
            data = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        with open('Configs/amounts.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(data)
            await ctx.send(f"```Account Registered!```")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Hey {ctx.author.name} you already got an account you silly person!")
````

No error messages just not sure how to check if the id exist or not.

Comment: You're checking for `ctx.message.author.id`, but you're adding `ctx.author.id`.

Comment: I tryed both and they still don't work

Answer (score 0):

You're testing a different variable than you're adding. Also, if `ctx.author.id` is an integer, you need to convert it to a string before testing.

There's also no need to load the JSON twice, just use the data returned by the first load.

````
async def register(ctx):
    with open('Configs/amounts.json') as f:
        usersidlel = json.load(f)
    if str(ctx.author.id) not in usersidlel:
        usersidlel[str(ctx.author.id)] = {'cash': 100, 'bank': 100}
        with open('Configs/amounts.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(usersidlel, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            await ctx.send(f"```Account Registered!```")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Hey {ctx.author.name} you already got an account you silly person!")
````